# How to create multiple test case in Allure report python

Tags: python, python-3.x, allure

I am trying to integrate allure report with python, so i have a single python class(Unit test)
which contains three methods setup, test, tearDown
In test method i read a excel file[loop through it] and verify some content
but in allure report only 1 test is displayed, Is there any way to mark this looping method as a individual test case, so that in allure reported multiple test cases should be displayed.

Comment: I am in similar situation. Following for any suggestions.

Comment: @user29496 You can use pandas library to convert excel to json and then. use ddt library to acheive data driven approach

Answer (score 0):

A testcase is a function.
So you could turn to pytest.mark.parametrize.